# c++ get supported camera resolutions and frame rate OSX

Tags: c++, macos, qt, ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg to record a video from a connected camera. I would like to be able to retrieve the supported camera resolution and framerate. Unfortunately this is currently not supported in ffmpeg on OSX. Are there other solutions out there? I've searched google and stackoverflow but the best I could find was a solution for windows using dshow.

I imagine this is possible with avfoundation but I don't have any experience with it. I am also using qt (not quicktime, the qt framework) so it would have to be compatible with that. :)

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

In Qt (starting from 5.3 version) you have [`QCamera`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cameraoverview.html)

```
foreach (const QCameraInfo &cameraInfo, QCameraInfo::availableCameras()) {
    QCamera *camera= new QCamera(cameraInfo);
    QMediaRecorder *recorder = new QMediaRecorder(camera);
    // DO queries on QMediaRecorder
}
```

You can check here the [`QMediaRecorder`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediarecorder.html) docs

Moreover [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cameraoverview.html) is an introduction.

Comment: Shouldn't the camera be queried and not the recorder? On the documentation the "suportedResolutions" function is related to encoding not the camera itself. In any case, unfortunately QMultimedia is still lacking for both windows and Mac as you can se here -> http://wiki.qt.io/Qt_5.5.0_Multimedia_Backends 

When I try to query QCamera for the supported resolutions and framerate I always get an empty list (even after loading the camera).